# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 in Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi when I try to run my app in Xcode 7.1 on device , I am getting the following error. Can you pls let me know the issue. It runs fine on simulator.

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADAuthenticationContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoadingViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: is it a normal Xcode template or u using third party frameworks/projects ?

Comment: It depends on what a `ADAuthenticationContext` is.  If it's part of a library/framework, you need to link it into your app.  If it's defined in source code, you need to add it to your project and build it into your target.

Comment: I have just included the ADAL library .a file in the project, have added the necessary headers and have set otherlinkerflags to "-ObjC".

Comment: Simple Solution
Go to Target ->Linking -> other linker Flag and add $(inherited) in other linker flag in both Debug and Release.

Comment: Could also be that required frameworks needed for that particular framework you need may not be linked. Double check the list of frameworks needed for that particular module or framework and link those in the build.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that library which consists of the class `ADAuthenticationContext` isn't compiled for `arm64` architecture, only for `armv7` / `armv7s`.

You can disable `arm64` support in your project by modifying **Supported Architectures** and **Valid Architectures** in **Build Settings**, then for this case compilation and linking should work.

Note that App Store won't accept your app without `arm64` support.

Try to update your library or recompile it by yourself properly if possible.

Comment: So if the App Store won't accept the app without arm64 support, what's the point of disabling the arm64 architecture? Realistically, the only option is to not include that framework - correct?

Comment: You could have your distribution behind the app store - e.g. enterprise in-house builds. Then app store requirements are not sufficient for you. In case of app store distribution - my last sentence in the answer - "Try to update your library or recompile it by yourself properly if possible". To remove the library is the worst or maybe not an option at all I think.